# How to search and replace matching brackets in a string using Python or posix tools

Tags: python, regex, sed, regexp-replace

I have one (i.e. a quick hack is ok for me) big (i.e. I can't do it manually) file containing "sort of Python/JSON parseable" data like this:

```
{
    "A": {
        {"foo": "bar"}
    }
}
```

..which I'd like to turn into a valid parse-able text  (could be Python, JSON, ..) to use in Python.

(Note: the above snippet *can* be *parsed* by Python but it's not a valid data structure since `set()` must contain hash-able elements)

Turning the curly braces behind `"A"` into brackets would turn `"A"` into a `list` which is Ok for me.

My first approach would be to search and replace certain braces to make it valid Python:

`"A": \{(properly braced subtext)\}` -> `"A": \[\1\]` leading to:

```
{
    "A": [
        {"foo": "bar"}
    ]
}
```

But how would I search and replace `{ .. }` -> `[ .. ]` when `}` can be part of the sub-string between `{` and `}`? (using common tools like `awk` or Pythons `re`)

Note: this sounds similar to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21682/how-to-replace-a-pair-of-brackets), but the answers do not recognize matching brackets.

Comment: Fixing malformed data usually requires patching a parser. I'm not sure that regular expressions is a tool which should be used for such as tasks. Writing universal solution could take a while. Will be good to add more samples from your *(big!) file*

Comment: @frans Can you provide a few more examples of the malformed json data?

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion, in pseudo code:

- Loop through each character in the text
- If a { is found, add 1 to a variable *bracketcounter*
- If a } is found, and bracketcounter is 1, you have found your matching bracket
- If a } is found, and bracketcounter is more than 1, deduct 1 from
  bracketcounter
- If a } is found, and bracketcounter is less than 1,
  there is a mis-match
- If the text ends and bracketcounter is not 0, there's also probably a mis-match in there

Comment: What if key or value contains `{` or `}`?

Comment: That's a valid point which would be solved by a fully syntax aware search/replace mechanism, but luckily I don't have this problem